# Data explorer query for questions per year, 2009 - 2016

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm on [Query Stack Exchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new). I'm trying to find the statistics for the number of questions asked each year from 2009 through 2016. On the right side of the page there is a box to select query items based on the schema.

I'm having trouble understanding how to extract the question count. I understand the WHERE clause to limit the counts within a range to the year in question.

My question is, where is the question count available? How do I extract it from the database?

Comment: You need to *aggregate*. Group by a criteria, then use the COUNT function. This is a basic SQL query question more than a SEDE question.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [How to use count and group by at the same select statement](//stackoverflow.com/q/2722408)

Comment: Or you could just use: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/625055/count-questions-by-year

Comment: @JonClements - that query is incorrect. It queries posts without constraining them to questions only.

Comment: @Oded I was pondering that... probably best to throw the relevant posttypeid where clause in... however, can posts exist in isolation from questions and do non-questions have a title? If not, then the count on the title might be taking care of that in a round-about way...

Comment: @Oded the results seem to tie up with a quick check like: `is:q created:2009..2009`

Comment: Yes, only questions will have titles, so may have gotten lucky with that query, @JonClements

Comment: @Oded yeah... wasn't my query and it had a fair few forks and upvotes and it looked okay. However, agree that an explicit filter on the PostType wouldn't go amiss :)

Answer (score 3):

The following [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/683694) does that for you, for questions, answers, deleted questions and answers as well as the count of created wiki's

```
select year(creationdate)
     , sum(case when posttypeid=1 and deletiondate is null then 1 else 0 end) as Q
     , sum(case when posttypeid=2 and deletiondate is null then 1 else 0 end) as A
     , sum(case when posttypeid=1 and deletiondate is not null then 1 else 0 end) as [ deleted Q]
     , sum(case when posttypeid=2 and deletiondate is not null then 1 else 0 end) as [deleted A]
     , sum(case when posttypeid=4 and deletiondate is null then 1 else 0 end) as [tag excerpt]
     , sum(case when posttypeid=5 and deletiondate is null then 1 else 0 end) as [tag wiki]
from postswithdeleted       
group by year(creationdate)
```

Instead of using the count aggregate I use a sum aggregate and use a case statement to return either a 1 or 0 per row if that row meets certain criteria, like Posttypeid =1 to denote a Question and posttypeid=2 to denote an answer.
Once that sums are done you can simply group the results per year by using the year function over the creationdate attribute of the postswithdeleted table.

Notice how I used the table postswithdeleted to also include the deleted posts. If you're only interested in just still visible posts today you could simply use the posts table. See this [database schema for more info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100)

And as we all love pictures, here is the graph:
[image]

As 2017 is not yet complete don't be alarmed by the dramatic drop currently visible...